# Picker for repeatable period of time in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, datepicker

I would like to display picker component that will pick a day and month that should be repeated.

In a result user could get a repeatable data:

eg. *Repeat fourth day of month every month* or *Repeat first day of month every two months*

Is there any standard UI component in Android that could be capable of allowing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two [`NumberPicker` widgets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html). `NumberPicker` is native to API Level 11, and there is probably a backport of it floating around somewhere.